# rust E0061: Some(A) is not the same as Some(match ... =>A)

Tags: rust, match

This code compiles fine:

```
Some(match head.path {
  "/" => Hello,
  "/num" => GetNum,
   p if p.starts_with('/') => HelloName(p[1..].to_string()),
   _ => PageNotFound
 }, RecvMode::Buffered(1024), scope.now() + Duration::new(10, 0))
```

If I change it to

```
Some(Hello, RecvMode::Buffered(1024),
         scope.now() + Duration::new(10, 0))
```

I get

```
error: this function takes 1 parameter but 3 parameters were supplied [E0061]
```

Why? Does match construction same semantics as

```
x>0?A:B
```

?

Function return value is declared as

```
Option<(Self, RecvMode, Time).
```

I was asked to provide MCVE, but I am not ready for that, that's why I'll give a [link to sample](https://github.com/tailhook/rotor-http/blob/master/examples/hello_world_server.rs), which I'm trying to change. To build it, add following dependencies to cargo.ml:

> rotor = "0.6.3" 
>   rotor-http = "0.7.0"

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it ensures that answers are really adapted for the situation described AND that there is no typo in your question.

Comment: Are you sure your first example compiles?  The linked sample does have the extra `()` to make the tuple.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson, excuse me, it wouldn't compile. Should I delete the question?

Comment: *but I am not ready for that* — you can take all the time you want **before you ask a question** to make it good. All the syntax errors show that you didn't spend much time on the question to start with. If you don't care to spend time to ask a good question, why should someone take the time to provide a good answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code from your question does not compile. In your sample on GitHub though you have the correct tuple-constructing syntax.

So for both your first and second example in the question: add parentheses around the tuple values to construct it:

```
Some((Hello, RecvMode::Buffered(1024),
         scope.now() + Duration::new(10, 0)))
```

You want to pass a tuple to an Option-Enum, you have to first construct the tuple.

Comment: please give some comment about double parentness, why do I need (())? Thanx!

Comment: `Some(x)` returns an `Option` filled with `x`.
`(a, b, c)` constructs a tuple.
So if you want an `Option` filled with a tuple, you have to first construct a tuple and then pass it to `Some`:
`Some((a, b, c))`